# When the code is run it doesn't output anything

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, user-input, bufferedreader

This was the part of a codevita-2020 problem called "constellations".

I tried solving the question using Java. I have built the logic but faced difficulty while trying to take input in a char array.

(There is a space between each line)

Problem statement :
Three characters { #, *, . } represents a constellation of stars and galaxies in space. Each galaxy is demarcated by # characters. There can be one or many stars in a given galaxy. Stars can only be in shape of vowels { A, E, I, O, U } . A collection of * in the shape of the vowels is a star. A star is contained in a 3x3 block. Stars cannot be overlapping. The dot(.) character denotes empty space.

Given 3xN matrix comprising of { #, *, . } character, find the galaxy and stars within them.

Note: Please pay attention to how vowel A is denoted in a 3x3 block in the examples section below.

Example 1

```
   Input

    18

    * . * # * * * # * * * # * * * . * .

    * . * # * . * # . * . # * * * * * *

    * * * # * * * # * * * # * * * * . *

    Output
    U#O#I#EA
```

MY CODE:

```
package codevita;

//constellations - codevita

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

public class constellations {
    static public BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    static public PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    static List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    static int main = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        System.out.println();
        String line[] = new String[3];
        int x = line.length;
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 3; j++) {
            line[j] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
        }
        char []line1 = line[0].toCharArray();
        char []line2 = line[1].toCharArray();
        char []line3 = line[2].toCharArray();
        int count = 0,main = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < line1.length; k++){
            if(line1[k] =='#'){
                count++;
            }
        }
        int split[] = new int [n];
        for(int l = 0; l < line1.length; l++){
            if(line1[l] =='#'){
                split[l] = l;
            }
        }
        // for A
        for(int i = 2; i< n; i++){
            // for A
            if(line1[i] =='#') {
                i++;
            }
            if(line1[i]== '.' && line1[i-1]== '*' &&line1[i-2]== '.' &&line2[i]== '*' && line2[i-1]== '*' &&line2[i-2]== '*' && line3[i]== '*' && line3[i-1]== '.' &&line3[i-2]== '*'){
                result.append('A');
                if(split[i] != 0){
                    result.append('#');
                }
                System.out.print(result.toString());
                main++;
            }
            // for E
            else if(line1[i]== '*' && line1[i-1]== '*' &&line1[i-2]== '*' &&line2[i]== '*' && line2[i-1]== '*' &&line2[i-2]== '*' && line3[i]== '*' && line3[i-1]== '*' &&line3[i-2]== '*'){
                result.append('E');
                if(split[i] != 0){
                    result.append('#');
                }
                main++;
            }
            // for I
            else if(line1[i]== '*' && line1[i-1]== '*' &&line1[i-2]== '*' &&line2[i]== '.' && line2[i-1]== '*' &&line2[i-2]== '.' && line3[i]== '*' && line3[i-1]== '*' &&line3[i-2]== '*'){
                result.append('I');
                if(split[i] != 0){
                    result.append('#');
                }
                main++;
            }
            // for O
            else if(line1[i]== '*' && line1[i-1]== '*' &&line1[i-2]== '*' &&line2[i]== '*' && line2[i-1]== '.' &&line2[i-2]== '*' && line3[i]== '*' && line3[i-1]== '*' &&line3[i-2]== '*'){
                result.append('O');
                if(split[i] != 0){
                    result.append('#');
                }
                main++;
            }
            // for U
            else if(line1[i]== '*' && line1[i-1]== '.' &&line1[i-2]== '*' &&line2[i]== '*' && line2[i-1]== '.' &&line2[i-2]== '*' && line3[i]== '*' && line3[i-1]== '*' &&line3[i-2]== '*'){
                result.append('U');
                if(split[i] != 0){
                    result.append('#');
                }
                main++;
            }
            
        }
        if(main >= (n-count)/x) {
            out.println(result.toString());
        }
        sc.close();
        out.close();
    }

    static int[] readArray(int n) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] a = new int[n];
        String[] data = reader.readLine().split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = Integer.parseInt(data[i]);
        }
        sc.close();
        return a;

    }
}


> It shows no output when I run this.
```

Comment: Put System.out.println statements throughout your code and narrow down the part of the code that doesn't produce the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't reliably work to read `System.in` both via `BufferedReader reader` and via `Scanner sc`. You have to decide on only one way to read the input. The probably simplest fix is to change

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

to

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(reader);
```

---

Then, you didn't take the space between the characters into account. You can fix this by removing the spaces at an early stage; change

```
            line[j] = sc.nextLine();
```

to

```
            line[j] = sc.nextLine().replace(" ", "");
```

---

Also, the logic to insert `#` in the output is wrong. To fix, just change

```
            if(line1[i] =='#') {
                i++;
            }
```

to

```
            if (line1[i] == '#') result.append('#');
```

Note that this still won't print `#` at the beginning, because you start the loop only at `int i = 2;`.

Answer (score 0):

int n=18,x1,y1;
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

```
    char x[][]=new char[3][n];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            x[i][j]=sc.next().charAt(0);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(x[0][i]=='#' && x[1][i]=='#' && x[2][i]=='#')
        {
            System.out.print("#");
        }
        else if(x[0][i]=='.' && x[1][i]=='.' && x[2][i]=='.')
        {}
        else
        {
            char a,b,c,a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2;
            x1 = i;
            a = x[0][x1];
            b = x[0][x1+1];
            c = x[0][x1+2];
            a1 = x[1][x1];
            b1 = x[1][x1+1];
            c1 = x[1][x1+2];
            a2 = x[2][x1];
            b2 = x[2][x1+1];
            c2 = x[2][x1+2];
            if(a=='.' && b=='*' && c=='.' && a1=='*' && b1=='*' && c1=='*' && a2=='*' && b2=='.' && c2=='*')
            {       
                System.out.print("A");
                i = i + 2;
            }
            if(a=='*' && b=='*' && c=='*' && a1=='*' && b1=='*' && c1=='*' && a2=='*' && b2=='*' && c2=='*')
            {       
                System.out.print("E");
                i = i + 2;
            }
            if(a=='*' && b=='*' && c=='*' && a1=='.' && b1=='*' && c1=='.' && a2=='*' && b2=='*' && c2=='*')
            {       
                System.out.print("I");
                i = i + 2;
            }
            if(a=='*' && b=='*' && c=='*' && a1=='*' && b1=='.' && c1=='*' && a2=='*' && b2=='*' && c2=='*')
            {       
                System.out.print("O");
                i = i + 2;
            }
            if(a=='*' && b=='.' && c=='*' && a1=='*' && b1=='.' && c1=='*' && a2=='*' && b2=='*' && c2=='*')
            {       
                System.out.print("U");
                i = i + 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Please format your code. The first few lines are outside the code blocks. 2. Please add some explanation. Answers need to have some explanation alongside the code so the users understand what the problem is and why the fix works.